# How can we redirect a url to another one if it is not available in code igniter?

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have changed the structure of my code igniter website and removed some old urls or which will not available. Unfortunately these pages are index by Google and i want to redirect those pages to the new url.

For eg. http://example.com/ar/properties/details/Testing-pages to http://example.com/ar/properties/home/details/Testing-pages(new ur)

Here i used the Property folder --> home.php and home_details.php

htaccess files:

**1# inside the root:**

```
Options +Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mysite\.com\/" [R=301,L]

</IfModule>
```

**2# inside the application folder:**

```
Options -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
<Files ~ ".(php*|s?p?x?i?html|cgi|asp|php3|php4|pl|htm|sql|tar|gz)$">
deny from all
</Files>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172058/codeigniter-301-redirect-with-router-for-old-url-and-remaning-no-redirect , remember add $this->load->helper('url'); or "traditional way" changing .htaccess

Comment: In what directory path is your main CI .htaccess located right now?

Comment: i can find two .htaccess files in the CI .#1- /public_html  and #2 - /public_html/application.

Comment: ok, can you provide both .htaccess in question?

Comment: @anubhava Please have a look.

Comment: So you wan to insert `/home/` in URLs after `ar/properties`?

Comment: @anubhava yes it should be /ar/properties/home/details/test-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this code in site root .htaccess:

```
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(mysite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(ar/properties)/(details.*)$ /$1/home/$2 [L,NC,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: thank you for the help.This is working for me.But i face another issues.in the case  /ar/properties/details/...  is redirected to  /ar/properties/home/details/... ,but i have some other urls redirected with same condition which do not really want.E.g. **en/properties/property-for-rent/studio-for-rent/details/...**  redirected to **en/properties/home/property-for-rent/studio-for-rent/details/...** Here i want only redirect url with example.com/ar/properties/details/...   to example.com/ar/properties/home/details/...

Comment: OK try my updated rule after clearing your browser cache.