# Codeigntier redirect url to itself

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I have a problem in Codeigniter my one URL redirects to itself. My URL
`example.com/cardboard-boxes` 301 redirects to same URL `www.example.com/cardboard-boxes` in Codeigniter.

How to do this?

Comment: Can you share the code where you have problems

Comment: i have full website but my url redirect to its self this is the problem

Comment: Than share your config if you thing it a config issue... edit your question

Comment: my question is that i have clone my website to another  now its working fine but my issue is that same product page redirect to same page with 301

Comment: Is this a canonical non-www to www redirect? "How to do this?" - Or how to _fix_ this?

Comment: I think this will be helpfull for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20172058/codeigniter-301-redirect-with-router-for-old-url-and-remaning-no-redirect?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Best way to redirect same page:

```
redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```